# Tool to extrapolate data

Tags: online-resources, extrapolation

I have daily data.

```
6.5315
4.9240
4.3253
3.9703
3.5932
3.2923
3.0785
3.4432
2.6213
2.4083
2.2602
2.1614
2.1351
2.0412
```

[image]

It looks like exponential function or something similar.
Is there tool possibly online that may give extrapolated function or functions.
e.g. k1*e^(k2*x), k1*e^(k2*x) + C, a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d, etc

and print next values and estimate step number when it will reach 1.0

I need something simple when I get these numbers. Right now I print and continue line by hand.

Comment: http://www.xuru.org/rt/TOC.asp

Comment: Exactly! Thank You! Put it in answer and I will mark question as answered.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+%7B6.5315%2C4.9240%2C4.3253%2C3.9703%2C3.5932%2C3.2923%2C3.0785%2C3.4432%2C2.6213%2C2.4083%2C2.2602%2C2.1614%2C2.1351%2C2.0412%7D, and, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B6.5315%2C4.9240%2C4.3253%2C3.9703%2C3.5932%2C3.2923%2C3.0785%2C3.4432%2C2.6213%2C2.4083%2C2.2602%2C2.1614%2C2.1351%2C2.0412%7D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regression tools at http://www.xuru.org/rt/TOC.asp. For you example, I got y = $5.549298703 e^{-8.661804988·10^{-2} x}$.